# How is eclipse setting the include paths in Paths and Symbols from Android NDK build files

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently using Eclipse Luna (4.4.1), ADT, and CDT plugin for Android NDK development on Windows 8.
 I would like to know, how does Eclipse (or the plugins) get the paths from Android.mk/Application.mk files in Project->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols. What is the algorithm/initial setting that retrieves the entries in this setting? And how are the paths propagated internally to Paths and Symbols? 
I've been changing Eclipse/NDK/SDK versions a couple of times and it never ever went smooth. After installing the new NDK and changing environment variables, Eclipse(cdt plugin) is again not picking up include directories. I've changed settings according to various suggestions I've found on stackoverflow, I've tried to remove various project/eclipse files, re-install the plugins and remove and re-install eclipse...Didn't help.
Therefore, I would like to understand the algorithm that retrieves the entries in the directory (preferably without studying the source code).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project -> Android tools -> Add native support...

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. However, my question is more about how the setting from e.g. Application.mk propagate to Eclipse Paths and Symbols internally.
I know that I have to add native support and after last update of NDK I also tried to re-import the project into Eclipse, so this was necessary.